# How to create a custom select box and insert a Bootstrap Card inside it?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, flask

I am on Bootstrap 5 using Python Flask as the backend and trying to mimic the behavior shown in the screenshots below? For my result, I want to insert a Bootstrap [card](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/), inside an Input field, after searching and selecting them from the Dropdown, as shown in the screenshot. I am aware that there is no out of the box solution, but how should I get started with it?

Step 1
[image: Step 1]

Step 2
[image: Step 2]

Step 3
[image: Step 3]

Comment: Provide your code what you tried.. How can community helps based on Images

Answer (score 0):

Here it is, I focused on functionality rather than design. You can better design as shown in your images.

I added two person details by default since you didn't mentioned anything

```js
var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
var search = document.getElementById('search');
var options = document.getElementById('options');
var person = document.querySelectorAll('.each-search');
var txtVal, filter;

function searchFilter(){
    for(var i = 0; i < person.length; i++){
        txtVal = person[i].children[1].children[0].innerText;
        filter = search.value.toUpperCase();
        if(txtVal.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1){
            person[i].style.display = '';
        }else{
            person[i].style.display = 'none';
        }    
    }
}

search.onclick = function(){
    options.classList.toggle('d-none');
}

for (var i = 0; i < person.length; i++) {
    
    person[i].onclick = function() {

        const cardElement = "<div class='card'>" + 
        "<button type='button' class='close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button>" + 
        "<div class='left-img'><img class='card-img-top' src=''></div>" + 
        "<div class='details'>" + 
        "<div class='name'></div><div class='email'></div>" + 
        "</div></div>";
        wrapper.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", cardElement);

        const cardImg = document.querySelector('.card .left-img img');
        const cardName = document.querySelector('.card .details .name');
        const cardEmail = document.querySelector('.card .details .email');

        const imgLink = this.children[0].children[0].getAttribute('src');
        const name = this.children[1].children[0].innerHTML;
        const email = this.children[1].children[1].innerHTML;

        cardImg.src = imgLink;
        cardName.innerHTML = name;
        cardEmail.innerHTML = email;

        document.getElementById('options').classList.add('d-none');

        var closeBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('close');
        for(var i = 0; i < closeBtn.length; i++){
            closeBtn[i].onclick = function(){
                this.parentElement.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.search-container{
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 6px;
    z-index: 999;
}

.wrapper{
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 3rem
}

.left-img img{
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.details{
    padding-left: .5rem;
}

.card{
    position: relative;
    padding: .5rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row !important;
    width: 10rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.close{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    outline: 0 !important;
}

.each-search{
    padding: .5rem;
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}


.email{
    font-size: 10px;
}

.fas{
    margin-left: -30px;
}

input{
    outline: 0;
}

main{
    padding: 1rem;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>


<main>
    <div id='wrapper' class='wrapper'>
        <input id='search' onkeyup='searchFilter()'>
        <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i>
        <div id='options' class='search-container d-none'>
            <div class='each-search'>
                <div class='left-img'>
                    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/40x40/f71616/fff&text=JD">
                </div>
                <div class='details'>
                    <div class='name'>John Doe</div>
                    <div class='email'>JohnDoe@gmail.com</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='each-search'>
                <div class='left-img'>
                    <img src='https://dummyimage.com/40x40/00ff5f/fff&text=JS'>
                </div>
                <div class='details'>
                    <div class='name'>John Smith</div>
                    <div class='email'>Johnsmith@gmail.com</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

I tried understanding your images and made like this. If anything needed comment down.